# SwiftUI Font scaling in a complex View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to make sure Text in a container to scale according to its parent. It works well when the container only contains one Text view, as following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FontScalingExperiment: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World ~!")
            .font(.system(size: 500))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding()
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .scaledToFill()  
        )
    }
}

struct FontScalingExperiment_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            FontScalingExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
            FontScalingExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 200, height: 200))
            FontScalingExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 300))
            FontScalingExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 400))
        }

    }
}
```

the result:

[image: Result]

However, when we have more complex View, we cant use same approach to automatically scale the text based on its parent size, for example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct IndicatorExperiment: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Line 2")
                Text("Line 3")
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("Line 4")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.yellow)
        )
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct IndicatorExperiment_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            IndicatorExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 100, height: 100))
            IndicatorExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 200, height: 200))
            IndicatorExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 300))
            IndicatorExperiment()
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 400))
        }
    }
}
```

Simply adding these 3 modifiers:

`.font(.system(size: 500))`
`.minimumScaleFactor(0.01)`
`.lineLimit(1)`

wont produce result like the first example; Text enlarged beyond the frame.
I did successfully, produce the result that I want by using GeometryReader then scale the font size based on `geometry.size.width`. Is this the only approach for achieving the desired result in SwiftUI?

Comment: I have the exact problem you have, and I cannot find an answer anywhere. All works as expected until I put views into an HStack. Do you mind sharing your solution with GeometryReader?

Comment: GeometryReader gives us the height and width of the frame, using this size we can set the font accordingly. for example:

GeometryReader { g in
HStack {
...
}
.font(.system(size: g.size.width / ratio))
}

ratio is any number, to adjust the size. Need to do manual visual validation to make sure it render properly for your smallest frame.

Comment: Your solution works well. Visual inspection is the key. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You can try make all the `Text`s the same height. To do this you will need to set the padding and spacing explicitly, so this will scale rather than the fixed default values.

Also, the `Spacer()` didn't make much sense here - if the requirement was that all the `Text` stay the same size, the `Spacer` would just make *all* the text small. For `Text` to scale based on space, and where `Spacer` tries to use as much space as possible, it's a contradiction. Instead, I decided to just set the `VStack`'s `spacing` in the initializer.

Working code:

```
struct IndicatorExperiment: View {
    private let size: CGFloat
    private let padding: CGFloat
    private let primarySpacing: CGFloat
    private let secondarySpacing: CGFloat
    private let textHeight: CGFloat

    init(size: CGFloat) {
        self.size = size
        padding = size / 10
        primarySpacing = size / 15
        secondarySpacing = size / 40

        let totalHeights = size - padding * 2 - primarySpacing * 2 - secondarySpacing
        textHeight = totalHeights / 4
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: primarySpacing) {
            HStack {
                scaledText("Line 1")

                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: textHeight)

            VStack(spacing: secondarySpacing) {
                scaledText("Line 2")

                scaledText("Line 3")
            }
            .frame(height: textHeight * 2 + secondarySpacing)

            scaledText("Line 4")
        }
        .padding(padding)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.yellow)
        )
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: size, height: size)
    }

    private func scaledText(_ content: String) -> some View {
        Text(content)
            .font(.system(size: 500))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .frame(height: textHeight)
    }
}
```

Code to test with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                IndicatorExperiment(size: 100)

                IndicatorExperiment(size: 200)

                IndicatorExperiment(size: 300)

                IndicatorExperiment(size: 400)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Using `GeometryReader` and a `.minimumScaleFactor` modifier would probably the only way to scale text in a view. To have more control on sizing, one possible way is to provde the `.frame` size from the parent view.

Scalable Text View

```
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Text("Foo")
            .font(
                .system(size: min(geo.size.height, geo.size.width) * 0.95))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.05)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }
```

Parent View that uses the Scalable Text View

```
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ScaleableText()
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
    }
```